# Getting a key from an encrypted text and it's known value (AES256)

Tags: encryption, text, cryptography, aes

I'm just asking my question out of curiosity. I have a username and password encrypted with the AES256 algorithm. I know what the username is. Can I obtain the encryption key from a plain text and its encrypted form?

**Encrypted Texts:**

```
username={AES256}RcD9sa6OiCoQRtIvBUr0c0OEYYbXEi7UTMLvLK+VYIc=
password={AES256}FBZohDA1IXNgGjYGFv97aKiYzYZWArESEOe1j9U+S8o=
```

Plain Text of Username:

```
weblogic
```

My ultimate goal is to get the key and decode the password with this key.

Comment: Check [Why is AES resistant to known-plaintext attacks?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/1512)

Comment: Two answers: yes by doing "brute force " or no (see comment @Topaco)